# dropdown element value in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

the code should populate the source dropdown(listSW) with a column of csv, and on change event create another dropdown(listPC) populated with another column of csv.
Now I want to refresh the newly created dropdown when I change the value in the source. But it keeps creating new dropdown(copy of listPC) and keep appending to the div.

How can I refresh the values in the "listPC" dropdown dynamically on the change event of listSW.

here is the plunkr
https://embed.plnkr.co/UGXPZG/

Answer (score 3):

You are appending the select box on change.

So in your `populatePC` function remove the `listPC` select box first, then append it back with new values.

```
d3.select("#listPC").remove()
```

working code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ylbUMA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you Cyril. It worked. makes it easy to move forward with filters... thanks again

Comment: Hi, Arun, if Cyrill's answer fixed your problem, please accept it.